# Navegar por id de elemento en React v6

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom, enlace

Soy un nuevo desarrollador, actualmente me encuentro realizando un portafolio, y no lo hice por HTML básico, sino cree un proyecto de React V6. El inconveniente que tengo, es que no puedo desplazarme a la sección mediante #id como se suele manejar en un portafolio de HTML. He intentado con Routes / Route y no consigo hacerlo.

Algun consejo, para replicar el siguiente codigo en React?

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about-section" class="nav-link"><span>About</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#resume-section" class="nav-link"><span>Resume</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services-section" class="nav-link"><span>Services</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#skills-section" class="nav-link"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#projects-section" class="nav-link"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#blog-section" class="nav-link"><span>My Blog</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: supongo que lo que quieres es tener un navbar donde al presionar un elemento, react haga scroll hasta donde se encuentra el elemento?

Answer (score 2):

Si estas utilizando alguna biblioteca de estilos como bootstrap y no vez el resultado, esto puede ser por la propiedad `class` que en react es sustituida por `className`, aqui te dejo un link de la documentación de react js

Doc: https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-advanced/17/react-class-name

Si no estas utilizando ninguna libreria de estilos se necesita mas información acerca de tu problema, espero te haya servido amigo, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías scrollear la ventana directamente a ese componente html con javascript así:

```
document.getElementById('idDeSeccion').scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del hook `useRef` el cual se puede utilizar para acceder a los elementos del DOM.

```
//Importar el hook
import { useRef } from 'react'

//Declarar la constante que se va a exportar al final
const Home = () => {
  //Declarar las constantes para cada sección
  const homeSection = useRef()
  const aboutSection = useRef()
  const resumeSection = useRef()

  //Declarar las constantes que harán el scroll
  const scrollTohome = () => homeSection.current.scrollIntoView()
  const scrollToAbout = () => aboutSection.current.scrollIntoView()
  const scrollToResume = () => resumeSection.current.scrollIntoView()

  //Maquetar el HTML
  return (
    <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='ftco-nav'>
      <ul className='navbar-nav nav ml-auto'>
        <li className='nav-item' onClick={scrollTohome}><span>Home</span></li>
        <li className='nav-item' onClick={scrollToAbout}><span>About</span></li>
        <li className='nav-item' onClick={scrollToResume}><span>Resume</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='any-class-for-div' ref={homeSection}>
      ...
    </div>
    <div className='any-class-for-div' ref={aboutSection}>
      ...
    </div>
    <div className='any-class-for-div' ref={resumeSection}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```